# How to pull into all branches?

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request

I'm contributing to a project on GitHub.

I did the following:

1. forked the repo
2. clone the forked repo
3. created a local branch in my local repo
4. fixed a bug in the local branch
5. pushed the changes to my forked repo
6. made a pull request from that new branch

After many days, I got some comments and I have to make some more changes.

But their code has changed a lot since then. If I have to make a pull request again, I must update my new branch with their updated code and merge my changes.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**:

Before any of this my `git log` looked like this:

> commit A "feature done" (latest, what I wanted to push)
>
> commit B "feature still acting weird"

I exactly did as VonC suggested (except that I was in my feature branch when I `fetch`ed).

My `rebase` had conflicts.
When I tried resolving them I was surprised to find that it was rebasing commit `B` and not `A` over the upstream master. I've checked this many times: `git log` shows exactly what I showed.

Why is it rebasing a **previous** commit of mine over the upstream master?

**EDIT**:
I fixed the above issue by squashing my 2 commits `A` and `B` into one.
Don't know why it happened though...

Comment: You might have created a feature branch for your change?

Comment: So in that case you can merge the remote branch into your feature branch so that you will have all the changes and then push the changes into feature branch and after that you can create a Pull request.

Comment: Which GIT client your using

Comment: @eatSleepCode, I use it from the terminal.

Comment: check [git tutorial](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial) for how to merge branches

Comment: You can cherry pick your change to their branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- add the original repo as a new remote:

  ```
  git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo
  ```
- fetch from "upstream"

  ```
  git fetch upstream
  ```
- rebase your brach on top of upstream/master

  ```
  git checkout yourBranch
  git rebase upstream/master
  ```
- force a push to your fork: **that will update your pull request automatically**:

  ```
  git push --force origin yourBranch
  ```

Comment: what happens if I make a pull request on the main reposotory (sic) if it is way ahead of my forked one? This would happen if I attended to the bug after many months in which time the main code would have gone ahead and possibly made conflicting changes.

Comment: @learner that is what the `git fetch` + `git rebase` is for: the fetch will bring the latest of the main repo, and the rebase will replay tour work on top of that most up-to-date main repo commit. Your pull request will done with the most recent version of that main repo.

Comment: I understand, but what if I didn't do that? Would it become a *dirty* pull request?

Comment: @learner you can rebase your "dirty" pull request on top of upstream/master in an interactive way: `git rebase --interactive`. That way, you can edit/drop/squash any commit you want, in order to get the clean history you want the upstream repo to see. The main point is: whatever you will push back to your branch in your fork will update your pull request automatically.

Comment: okay, but GitHub shows you a diff when you do a pull request right? How will that diff look if the changes are conflicting like in the case I mentioned? I mean, how will GitHub tell us it is a bad request? If I simply push to my forked repo without rebasing it should still update the pull request like you said. But will that not be a failed pull request? What will such a pull request look like in GitHub?

Comment: @learner the symptom of a bad pull request is that it doesn't apply in a fast-forward manner,  without any conflicts.  It isn't a question of diff, but of applying your commits on top of the most up-to-date upstream repo commits.

Comment: Ok, I'm particular about diff, because that is how reviewers will review my code at the first few stages. They shouldn't see unrelated changes introduced by later commits which I didn't pull, right?

Comment: @learner Exactly: that is what the rebase is for: replay your commits on top of the most recent version of upstream repo. The resulting diff will show only your work.

Comment: @learner Well, if the rebase seems too complex/strange, you can rename your current branch, make your branch on top of upstream/master, and cherry-pick your commits (from your renamed branch), one  by one. That way, you will control the order of commits to apply.